# Unable to install fully signed apk file to hero live device version 2.3

Tags: android, apk, adb, dalvik

I've kind of kicked my own butt for 3 hours trying to get this to work...

Can't get a fully signed apk file to install on my htc hero.
The target versions are min: 3, target: 15
The hero is running 9

I am using the htc sync utility to install, and have successfully installed other
3rd party apk files.

The debuggable tag has been removed.

Error message:
Installation failure. Please check the file and ensure that there is 
sufficient space of the mobile for installation.
That's not a typo, it says 'of the mobile'

I have tried many different manifest configurations, but all with the same result.
There is about 100 mg memory and 2 gb on sd available.
The apk file is about 10k, and is signed.

I have had no trouble running any builds from the device on adb/eclipse.

I have been trying with multiple files all afternoon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First enable installing applications from unknown sources in settings. Then there are a few ways to proceed:

- Move the .apk to the device's sd card and use a file manager
- Email the .apk as an attachment and open it on the device
- Put the .apk in Dropbox or Google Drive or some other file sharing service and open the .apk on the device.

Comment: Adding to this, you can also try to install it through ADB. `adb install <path_to_apk/app.apk>`

Comment: I have no problems with ADB. Thanks Victor KP for the useful list. I was able to use ES file manager to open the apk file from the device, after transferring it directly to the SD from my pc.

Comment: Unknown sources was not the issue, I should have listed that above.
I guess that the problem is a bug with HTC sync, but I don't know the exact issue. One problem during installing from ES file manager was that no apk would install in place of an app already under that name. Once they were removed, there was no problem.

Comment: I've never used HTC Sync, so it could just be something weird. When you said that no apk would install in place of an app with the same name, it could be a signatures issue. Basically, the system won't allow you to install an app of the same package name but different signature. If you were developing with a debug signature, then naturally installing the app with a release signature wouldn't work. Its a security thing

Comment: That was exactly the problem with the file manager install, since I was trying to use different signatures with the same package. I wonder if it is a better practice to rename the package for the apk or to remove the debug versions from the device after debugging.

Comment: Its easier to just uninstall the debug version than rename the package and edit the package name in the manifest.